# how to detect a 5% deviation between more than 2 numbers

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, mean-absolute-deviation

Dear StackExchange Team

in the industry there are GAs generators that have hundreds of instrument measuring process values, such as pressure, temperatures, etc.

we have a simple case where a generator has 8 temperature sensors measuring pretty much the same but we need to generate an alert when any of the 8 sensors deviate more than 5%.

as an example i have

- Sensor 1: 1 psi
- Sensor 2: 1 psi
- Sensor 3: 1 psi
- Sensor 4: 1 psi
- Sensor 5: 1 psi
- Sensor 6: 1 psi
- Sensor 7: 1 psi
- Sensor 8: 1 psi

Deviation for the above is 0 but if one of the sensors change to

- Sensor 1: 1.06 psi
- Sensor 2: 1 psi
- Sensor 3: 1 psi
- Sensor 4: 1 psi
- Sensor 5: 1 psi
- Sensor 6: 1 psi
- Sensor 7: 1 psi
- Sensor 8: 1 psi

Sensor 1 changed to 1.06 which is 5.8% from Sensor 2, then this is an alert we need to generate.

another example is following, where the percentage change between the sensors is not more than 5%, so we dont have to generate an alert but as soon as any of the sensors pass 1.055, then we generate an alert

- Sensor 1: 1.05
- Sensor 2: 0.95
- Sensor 3: 1.05
- Sensor 4: 0.95
- Sensor 5: 1.05
- Sensor 6: 1.05
- Sensor 7: 0.95
- Sensor 8: 1.05

Would you be able to help me telling me what statitics tool i can use to alert such deviation?

i appreciate very much your help in advance.

Comment: Something like `if ((max(data)-min(data))/min(data) > 0.05) {print("ALERT!)}`. You can make this bit of R code (which I haven't tested but I believe will work) more complex so that it will tell you exactly what sensors differ and by how much, but that's the gist.